# how to save native text input to a txt file in corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, saving-data

my question is how to save a user text input to a .txt file in corona sdk.

So basically what I want to achieve is that when a user writes something into a text box and then presses the save button, the text from the textxbox saves to a .txt file into the system documents directory.

thansk for help! :)

here's the code :)

```
local function inputListener( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        -- user begins editing textBox
        print( event.text )

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

       local myfile = io.open( filePath, "w" )  
       myfile:write(textBox)  
       io.close(myfile)  



    elseif event.phase == "editing" then

        print( event.newCharacters )
        print( event.oldText )
        print( event.startPosition )
        print( event.text )

    end
end

local textBox = native.newTextBox( 200, 200, 280, 140 )
textBox.text = "This is line 1.\nAnd this is line2"
textBox.isEditable = true
textBox:addEventListener( "userInput", inputListener )
```

Comment: I tried "myfile:write(textBox.text)" and now I got the error: Attempt to index global 'textBox' (a nil value)

Comment: Perhaps you need to add "textBox.text = event.text" just below the "elseif event.phase == "ended" then" line.

Comment: still the same error :/

Comment: Try moving the variables above the function. If that does not work then I suggest just using the text you retrieve from the event.text variable and saving that directly to the file.

Comment: i have still the same error

Comment: I wish I could help you further, but I am unable to replicate the error from my own code and from using your code with the modified suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read through the documentation provided by Corona Labs here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html

Here is the merged code from the documentation and the code you provided. With this code I am unable to replicate the error you are mentioning in the comments, and as such I am unable to assist you further.

```
local textBox = native.newTextBox( 200, 200, 280, 140 )
textBox.text = "This is line 1.\nAnd this is line2"
textBox.isEditable = true

local function inputListener( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then

        -- user begins editing textBox
        print( event.text )

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

       local path = system.pathForFile( "myfile.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

       local file = io.open( path, "w" )
       file:write( textBox.text )
       io.close( file )
       file = nil 

    elseif event.phase == "editing" then

        print( event.newCharacters )
        print( event.oldText )
        print( event.startPosition )
        print( event.text )

    end
end
textBox:addEventListener( "userInput", inputListener )
```

Comment: yes the saving part of a hardcoded string is pretty easy, I have problems when I have a dynamic string which can be editet any time while the app is running. I want to save then the changed text. :) 

everytime I try to do this I get this error:

Bad argument #1 to 'write' (string expected, got nil)

Comment: Could you edit your initial response with some code; the code you are using for saving to file and the code you are using for updating the variable with the "dynamic string", please? Given the error you posted there, it would seem the variable you are storing the data in is not properly given the assosiation to the string you are inputting. Make sure you are initializing the saveData variable before the function/saving process AND that the data is actually stored in the string.

Comment: It would appear you are trying to save the textBox, rather then the text inside the box. Since the textBox is an object, you would have to write "myfile:write(textBox.text)" to retrieve the actual string contained in said textBox.

Comment: I tried "myfile:write(textBox.text)" and now I got the error: Attempt to index global 'textBox' (a nil value)

Comment: Perhaps you need to add "textBox.text = event.text" just below the "elseif event.phase == "ended" then" line.

Comment: I have one more question, I want to upload the .txt file to a remote server, I have it all figuered out and it sends the file in the simulator but not on a real device, I can only send a txt file ona a device if it's hardcoded..

Comment: Did you remember to add the permissions in the permissions config file? Also discussion/further questions is not really appreciated in comments. Hit up a new question.